# Command line android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I can't install the android sdkmanager. So I need to download the cmdline-tools before I can do that. But I have no idea to do it

I tried downloading a new sdk from android studio itself but its not working. Now I have no idea what to do.

Comment: More information please? :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.